# 3 table join counting nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where I have three tables; dealership, car and warehouse.  Dealership is related to car and car is related to warehouse.  How can a mysql query be constructed to determine the sum of the number of vehicles in the warehouses that were not sent to a dealer?

Here are the data tables:

```html
Dealer
Id   |   name     |                           
_____|____________|
D1   |  Dealer_1  |
D2   |  Dealer_2  |
D3   |  Dealer_3  |
D4   |  Dealer_4  |


Car
Id   |    name   | Dealer_id |
_____|___________|___________|
C1   |  auto_1|  |   D4      |
C2   |  auto_2   |   D4      |
C3   |  auto_3   |   null    |
C4   |  auto_4   |   D1      |
C5   |  auto_5   |   null    |
C6   |  auto_6   |   D3      |


Warehouse
Id   |    name   | Car_id    | vehical_count |
_____|___________|___________|_______________|
W1   | storage_1 |   C2      |   22          |
W2   | storage_2 |   C3      |   43          |
W3   | storage_3 |   C5      |   18          |
W4   | storage_4 |   C6      |   15          |
W5   | storage_5 |   C1      |    8          |
W6   | storage_6 |   null    |    2          |
W7   | storage_7 |   C3      |   37          |
W8   | storage_8 |   null    |   10          |
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your data.  The warehouse table clearly shows some sort of inventory, but against what are we supposed to be comparing this inventory?

Comment: Looking at `warehouse` and the `vehicle_count` column makes me believe that `car` doesn't mean an individual vehicle but a type. Then however, looking at `car` I don't see no vehicle count there (and also feel the dealer is misplaced there, there should rather be an delivery table or something). That indicates car is meant to be an individual vehicle. Or, if it isn't how to know how much if a type a dealer got? (Edit: Mhh, just realized that this is essentially the same point, that @TimBiegeleisen mentioned but more verbosely expressed. I'll leave it because of the latter.)

Comment: One dealer may have multiple cars.  One car model may be housed in multiple warehouses.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @brohjoe I'm also not sure what your question is asking.  So you have a warehouse, with a bunch of cars.  Where are the dealers storing their cars?

Comment: Is it not possible to construct a mysql query here to determine a vehical_count of total cars not connected with a dealer?

Comment: If you look at this more abstractly...A more generic question would be...I have 3 tables, table A, B and C.  Table A is related to table B.  Table B is related to table C.  How can I get a count of inventory_items in table C that are not related to table A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you warehouse cars not in the car table or in the car table with no dealer assigned.

```
SELECT
    SUM(w.vehical_count)
FROM
    Warehouse w
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Car c ON c.Id=w.Car_id
WHERE
    c.Dealer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: There is no `c.Car_id` (I think you meant `w.Car_id`) but that part of the `WHERE` clause is redundant anyway so you could remove it.

Comment: DormantVehicles causes an error in mysql, but deleting it clears up the query.  Thanks Ross.  I think this is correct.

Comment: @Nick - Updated answer to the correct alias, thank you.

Comment: @brohjoe - removed invalid alias