# Count null from joined table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, outer-join

I need a count of NULL from 2 tables that are joined in MySQL. Sample data like this:

```
datefield FROM TABLE calendar (contain dates from start to end of this year)
-----------
TABLE value (data stored)
+------------+-------+
| date       | keter |
+------------+-------+
| 2021-08-01 |    11 |
| 2021-08-04 |     0 |
| 2021-08-07 |    20 |
| 2021-08-08 |    15 |
| 2021-08-11 |     0 |
+------------+-------+
```

I am using the following query to combine and display data from calendar and value tables.

```
SELECT datefield,keter FROM calendar 
LEFT JOIN kehadiran ON datefield=tgl AND id_kar IN ('110101') 
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-15' GROUP BY datefield;

result :
+------------+-------+
| datefield  | keter |
+------------+-------+
| 2021-08-01 |    11 |
| 2021-08-02 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-03 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-04 |     0 |
| 2021-08-05 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-06 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-07 |    20 |
| 2021-08-08 |    15 |
| 2021-08-09 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-10 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-11 |     0 |
| 2021-08-12 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-13 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-14 |  NULL |
| 2021-08-15 |  NULL |
+------------+-------+
```

I use query based on this question ([3 table join counting nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604293/3-table-join-counting-nulls)), I didn't get the result I wanted. The query is this :

```
SELECT SUM(k.keter) FROM kehadiran k 
LEFT OUTER JOIN calendar c ON c.datefield = k.keter AND id_kar IN ('110101') 
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-12' AND k.keter is NULL;

result:
+--------------+
| SUM(k.keter) |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+

the result i wanted :
+--------------+
| SUM(k.keter) |
+--------------+
|           10 |
+--------------+
```

How should I count NULL from the joined table as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You swapped the tables in your last query which is incorrect. Use the query that worked and use `COUNT(*)` with `WHERE right_table.any_notnull_column IS NULL`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM calendar 
LEFT JOIN kehadiran k ON datefield=tgl AND id_kar IN ('110101')
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-15'
AND k.keter is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You sum up NULL in your query. And a Sum of NULL is NULL. You should just replace `SUM(k.keter)` with `COUNT(k.keter)`

[See](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1de09b185e0b69583651ffe133cee221) for a small example

Answer (score 1):

To count `NULL`s, you can use:

```
SUM(k.keter IS NULL)
```

Or:

```
COUNT(*) - COUNT(k.keter)
```